# Object Sending Client Sever Application in Java

Tags: java, object, server, client, typecasting-operator

I need Help regarding Client-Server Application Java (read Carefully)

I am developing Database in which on Server Side I have Class Products having some properties name,price_tag etc

On Client Side if I make a Same Product class with same properties then can I send Object to Server and Can Server receives Object with or without Type Casting of its Product Class or not ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the technology of client and server, and how are they connected ?? How are you sending the object, are you serialising it ??

Comment: localhost simple Lan connection through IPv4 or TCP

Comment: Using webservices? Rmi?? .. how is the client and server linked and how are you sending the object

Comment: No its not a serialize-able object , I just want to add the object to hibernate database sent from client to server ,Definitely server will add that object to Database

Comment: via Desktop Application

Comment: How are you sending the object ?

Comment: using ObjectOutputStream , I want to know if this method holds for sending Objects of same classes that is Products Class on both Server and Client Side

Comment: Or in simple word I want to merge the sent Product Object in Product Object of Server side

Comment: You need to type cast the object once read from ObjectInputStream